# Is it possible to specify the column in a for each loop of an array list? c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, foreach

I have an array list with two columns. I also have a foreach loop. Is it possible for me to specify to only loop column 1? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
foreach (object[] row in myArrayList)
 {
   foreach (object column in row) //I want to specify just the first column here
    {}
 }
```

Comment: How about just `row[0]`?

Comment: row is an array of columns

Comment: why on earth you are still using `ArrayList` ? use type-safe collections. And consider creating a class for your table instead of dealing with random objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such concept as rows or columns in C#. What you seem to have is a case of nested arrays, that is you have an array of rows, where as each row is an array in itself:

```
var myArrayList = new[] { new[] { obj1, obj2 }, new[] { obj3, obj4 } }
```

So if I get your question right, you would like to extract `obj1` and `obj3` for example, that would be the "first" column of `myArrayList`. You can't extract columns, but you can transform your array elements ("rows") into anything you like by using the LINQ `Select`:

```
var firstColumn = myArrayList.Select(row => row[0])
```

Then you can iterate over it:

```
foreach (object cell in firstColumn)
{ ... }
```

BTW: Your variable name `myArrayList` could imply you are using an `ArrayList` rather than an array. It does not really make a difference: Arrays and all sorts of collections in C# all implement `IEnumerable`, which is the only prerequisite for using LINQ as well as `foreach`.

Comment: would I be better off with two individual arrays? one for each column

Comment: @user, this cannot be said in general. It depends on what you are mainly doing with your data. If most of your crucial accesses are column-based, it might be a "yes". But that would have consequences on other decisions, for example whether to use a column-based database (if your data is coming from a database).

Answer (score 0):

Following code will do for you

```
 foreach (object[] row in myArrayList)
 {
   object column =  row[0]
   //Do what ever you want to do with column
 }
```